# Alamofire, Session Manager limit retry count

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire's SessionManager to make requests to my API services.

Is there a way to limit the retry counts in Alamofire?

I'm using the new RequestAdapter and RequestTrier Protocols to provide a retry mechanims in Alamofire v4.

I want to limit retries up to 5. If after 5 Retries a new request shouldn't be done.

```
class VMRetrier: RequestAdapter, RequestRetrier {

public func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest) throws -> URLRequest {
    return urlRequest;
}

func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion) {

    if let response = request.task?.response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 401 {
        VMLogger.shared.debug(message: "Trying to get a token")
        let _ = AuthService.shared.login(email: "a@a.com", password: "test34")
                           .then(execute: { (response) in
                                completion(true, 0.0)
                           })
    }
    else {
        completion(false, 0.0)
    }
} }
```

Usage:

```
internal let sessionManager = SessionManager()

override init() {
    super.init()
    sessionManager.adapter = VMRequestAdapter()
    sessionManager.retrier = VMRetrier()
}
```

**UPDATE**
There is a new commit in alamofire to provide a retry count option.[Alamofire Commit](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/1672)

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: please see my update

Comment: Thanks for the info with the `retryCount` property in the requests

Answer (score 5):

I have solved this with Alamofire's `RequestRetrier` protocol:

```
class Retrier: RequestRetrier {

    var defaultRetryCount = 4
    private  var requestsAndRetryCounts: [(Request, Int)] = []
    private  var lock = NSLock()

    private func index(request: Request) -> Int? {
        return requestsAndRetryCounts.index(where: { $0.0 === request })
    }

    func addRetryInfo(request: Request, retryCount: Int? = nil) {
        lock.lock() ; defer { lock.unlock() }
        guard index(request: request) == nil else { print("ERROR addRetryInfo called for already tracked request"); return }

        requestsAndRetryCounts.append((request, retryCount ?? defaultRetryCount))
    }

    func deleteRetryInfo(request: Request) {
        lock.lock() ; defer { lock.unlock() }
        guard let index = index(request: request) else { print("ERROR deleteRetryInfo called for not tracked request"); return }

        requestsAndRetryCounts.remove(at: index)
    }

    func should(_ manager: SessionManager, retry request: Request, with error: Error, completion: @escaping RequestRetryCompletion){

        lock.lock() ; defer { lock.unlock() }

        guard let index = index(request: request) else { completion(false, 0); return }
        let (request, retryCount) = requestsAndRetryCounts[index]

        if retryCount == 0 {
            completion(false, 0)
        } else {
            requestsAndRetryCounts[index] = (request, retryCount - 1)
            completion(true, 0.5)
        }
    }
}
```

Should be used this way:

```
let manager = SessionManager()
let retrier = Retrier()
// ...
manager.retrier = retrier
```

then

```
let request = manager.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)

retrier.addRetryInfo(request: request)

request.response { r in
    self.retrier.deleteRetryInfo(request: request)
}.responseApiJSON { (r: DataResponse<JSONObject>) in
    // You code here
}
```

Comment: This would be nice to have built into the Alamofire project

Comment: What if I am not using any session manager here ? How to go about using request retrier

Comment: The request object now has a `retryCount` field @neoneye